# Mail downloads immediately visible

Tags: mail.app

when I read appended docs in Mail, it saves each one of them automatically Mail Downloads in separate obscurely named folders. The same docs can be saved so numerous times. Can I get rid of these folders so that I see immediately what files were downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

In Mail Preferences, you can specify where the attachments are saved.

[image: mail]

Check this settings and decide what you want:

[image: downloads]

- **If you want it the old way**

Use Automator that will save **all** Attachments in a Folder of your choice. Then you can decide what to keep and what to delete.

[image: automator]
[image: automator]

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't solve my problem. Appended docs are saved in Mail downloads. Since the last MACOS update each doc is saved hidden within a separate folder. To see each individual document requires 2 operations, opening the Mail download folder, then the 2nd folder. Thus inadvertantly the same operations can be repeated numerous times, leading to saving the sames docs again and again. But this is not visible since they are individually embedded in separate folders with strange names such as "79DD19EE-2461-46DC-B8EB-424A3A1E831F", thus unnecessarily jamming the Mail download folder.

Comment: You are talking about the temporary folders in Mail. That is the way Mail works. But if you want to save a appended to your specified folder just ignore those or delete them.

Comment: Mail has to download it first for you to be able to see it. Is your question how to Delete those located in Mail library ?

Comment: Thanks Buscar, I do know how to delete them, except this implies that I check what was saved properly and what is still in the temporary download file. This is a waste of time. The previous OS had all docs saved straight in the download folder, so it was easy to track duplicons. I don't mind that it needs to save them 1st so that I can read them. I mind the intermediate folder.

Comment: It only saves them temporally. It will delete them if you set it as "remove after quit" or "remove when email is deleted". So you do not have to do anything other then actually save the attachments you want to keep in your specified folder. If you re-download that same email from the server it will come (again) with the attachment, if you do not have the delete from server set up. This way you can be sure not to have missed to save a important attachment.

Comment: In order not to forget to download (save) an attachment you can create a very simple Automator action for that. It will save all attachments to a specified folder, after which you can go there and delete them manually.

Comment: Thanks. To begin with you're right I should jump and get a crash course in Automator. It has been so long I decided so but never did. My settings are as described (remove when email is deleted). I checked, and they stay, when I delete the corresponding emails and upon quitting Mail... Bizarre

Comment: I did this test repeatedly g emials and quitting Mail) (deletinand the temporary files are still there...

Comment: Ok, I thought I was clear, mail will re-download the attachments to the temporary folder until you delete the attachments in the mail it self, not in the Mail Library. The library folder is not meant for regular users.